# Cannot start service peer0.org1.firstproject.com: b'OCI runtime create failed:

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to create my own-network in hyperledger fabric but got stuck because of below reason. I'm following chainHero tutorial for this with some changes like using my own organization name and peer's name. 
I have already tried a couple of solutions available but none of them worked for me hence asking this question. Any help would be appreciated.

> ### Error
>
> ```
> docker-compose up -d
> Creating network "firstproject-network_default" with the default driver
> Creating ca.org1.firstproject.com    ... done
> Creating orderer.firstproject.com ... done
> Creating peer1.org1.firstproject.com ... error
> Creating peer0.org1.firstproject.com ...
>  Cannot start service peer0.org1.firstproject.com: b'OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "exec: \\"peer\\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown'
> ```

### Docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '2'

networks:
  default:

services:
  orderer.firstproject.com:
    container_name: orderer.firstproject.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: orderer-base
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - GRPC_TRACE=all=true,
      - GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug

    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/firstproject.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      - ./artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/genesis.block
      - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/firstproject.com/orderers/orderer.firstproject.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls

    ports:
      - 7050:7050


  ca.org1.firstapplication.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest
    container_name: ca.org1.firstproject.com
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.firstproject.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.firstproject.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/78da3186373e52832b71dd83ec4d36ef84722a3e3ed15e8df214b482fe2723e7_sk
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.firstproject.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/78da3186373e52832b71dd83ec4d36ef84722a3e3ed15e8df214b482fe2723e7_sk
    ports:
      - 7054:7054
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.firstproject.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config


  peer0.org1.firstproject.com:
    container_name: peer0.org1.firstproject.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:

      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=firstproject
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.firstproject.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.firstproject.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.firstproject.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1.firstproject.com
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE=peer0.org1.firstproject.com

    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.firstproject.com/peers/peer0.org1.firstproject.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.firstproject.com/peers/peer0.org1.firstproject.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/tls

    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053
    depends_on:
      - orderer.firstproject.com
    links:
      - orderer.firstproject.com  
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - peer0.org1.firstproject.com  


  peer1.org1.firstproject.com:
    container_name: peer1.org1.firstproject.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:

      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=firstproject
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.firstproject.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.firstproject.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.firstproject.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_SKIPHANDSHAKE=true
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=org1.firstproject.com
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_SERVERHOSTOVERRIDE=peer1.org1.firstproject.com

    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.firstproject.com/peers/peer1.org1.firstproject.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.firstproject.com/peers/peer1.org1.firstproject.com/tls:/var/hyperledger/tls

    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    depends_on:
      - orderer.firstproject.com
    links:
      - orderer.firstproject.com  
    networks:
      default:
        aliases:
          - peer1.org1.firstproject.com
```

### Peer-base.yaml ##

```
version: '2'

services:
  peer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
    environment:
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_VM_DOCKER_ATTACHSTDOUT=true
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_USELEADERELECTION=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=false
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/var/hyperledger/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/var/hyperledger/msp

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: peer node start

  orderer-base:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
    environment:
      - FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=DEBUG
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of peer-base is incorrect

```
services:
  peer-base:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:latest
```

your image should be fabric-peer

```
services:
  peer-base:
  image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:latest
```

Would also highly recommend you don't use the latest tag as this tag will be removed in the future. You should specify the version you want to use.

Comment: I'm using this binary files  "hyperledger-fabric-linux-amd64-1.4.1-rc1.tar.gz"  but when I mentioned it   "image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:x86_64-1.4.1-rc1" it gives me error "ERROR: manifest for hyperledger/fabric-orderer:x86_64-1.4.1-rc1 not found"

Am I using the correct image ?

Comment: image: hyperledger/fabric-peer:1.4.1 should work for example. You don't need to specify the architecture and 1.4.1 has now been released.